# prettyDate() javascript function does not work in Firefox or Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, datetime

[John Resig's prettyDate()](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/) function works fine in Chrome and Safari, but returns "undefined" in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

See it for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/A3DAe/

Why is that?

(NB: Note that the timestring is the one provided by the Twitter api. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because that regex to "fix" the time is erroneous.

```
var date = new Date((time || "").replace(/-/g,"/").replace(/[TZ]/g," ")),
```

should be

```
var date = new Date((time || "").replace(/-/g,"/").replace(/TZ/g," ")),
```

The character class `[TZ]` in the broken version was turning "Thu" into "hu". I guess Firefox is just more picky about RFC 2822 dates.

*edit* — I'm not sure that what that's trying to do is remove the time zone ("TZ") delimiter, but I assume it is.